How to skip unwanted flush when using findBy... that is leading to: object references an unsaved transient instance
My problem lies probably in hibernate that flushes after findBy() method and throws error because updated entity is not set up yet.
My classes looks like this.
public class CodelistItem {
    @ToStringExclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "codelistItem", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<CodelistItemField> codelistItemFields = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class CodelistItemField {
    @ToStringExclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CODELIST_ITEM_FIELD_DEFINITION_ID", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private CodelistItemFieldDefinition codelistItemFieldDefinition;
}

public class CodelistItemFieldDefinition { //this one exists before any other classes are created
    private Long id;
    private String code;
}

The problem comes if I want to update codelist item.
I use a mapstruct that deletes all ItemFields, creates new ones, adds them into codelistItem.codelistItemFields and creates new Definition with code, being the only available information at the time and makes it easier in the future.
Then comes the problem:
I want to add the definition reference, but if I call codelistItemFieldDefinitionRepository.findByCodelistCodeAndCode(codelistItem.getCodelist().getCode(),codelistItem.getCodelistItemFields().get(0).getCodelistItemFieldDefinition().getCode()); i get the mentioned error ("org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing"). I expect some unwanted (by me) entity state check, but can someone explain the reason of the check and the possibilities how to fix this problem?
The real definition object is persisted, so I dont use cascade.ALL. (but I tried that and got an error "not-null property")
If all of this is done without transaction, it works, but transaction should be used, because other code and DB calls are executed.

By default, Hibernate flushes before committing a transaction and before JPQL/HQL and native SQL queries. However, this strategy can be changed using the EntityManager.setFlushMode() and Session.setHibernateFlushMode() methods.
You may want to use the COMMIT mode, in which Hibernate tries to delay flush until the end of the transaction if possible.
entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT)

Or the MANUAL mode, in which you are responsible for flushes yourself.
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
session.setHibernateFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);

For more information, see the Hibernate User Guide.
